# Find all Objects in a Collection with at least one matching property

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, lodash, angular-filters

I have an Array with Objects. In short

```
    Array =[  
    {id = 1, products='1,2'} //products consist of String with Products Seperates by','
    {id = 2, products='1'}  
    {id = 3, products='3'}  
    {id = 4, products='1,2,3'}
    {id = 5, products='2,3'}
    ...  
    ]
SelectedProd = ['2,3']// consists a String as well seperated by ','
```

This are all Displayed in a Table. Im writing now a Filter to show only the ones which are selected through a MultipleSelect.
Therefore I want filter all Objects where at least one Product is in `products`
So my Filter is getting the Objects and the Selected Products

```
.filter('filterByProd', () => {
          return (objects,prod) => {
            var filtered = [];
            /*
FIlter Array
*/
            return filtered;
          };
        });
```

If a User Selects `Product = '2,3'` it shall return me the Objects with the `id=1/3/4/5..`
As well clearly if nothing selected return all.
If possible using lodash but other solutions accepted as well.
The problem I have is the Functions are just listed in lodash Docu and cant read everyone which I need.
At the moment Iam stuck at

```
.filter('filterByProd', () => {
  return (items,prod) => {
    var filtered = [];
    filtered = _.filter(items,['products',prod]);
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

This is giving me out only the exact matches with `'2,3'` -> `Object = id=5` only.
I need something

```
filtered = findAllWhere(selectedProducts,iterateOverSendObjects(checkProductsOfObjects)+_.ifIsAtLeastOneOfSendProducts))
```

Comment: Why do you have a string for the products like `'2,3'` when it would make more sense in your problem to have an array with `[2,3]`? And it would be a simple matter of iteration through them

Comment: Im getting it like this from my Server.

Comment: Either way you will need to parse it. You can do it as soon as you get the data or when you are trying to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's intersection method to get your desired result.

```
var a = arr.filter(x => {
    return _.intersection(
             x.products.split(','), SelectedProd[0].split(',')
           ).length > 0;
```

Here's a working inline fiddle:

```js
var arr = [  
    {id : 1, products:'1,2'}, 
    {id : 2, products:'1'},  
    {id: 3, products:'3'},  
    {id : 4, products:'1,2,3'},
    {id : 5, products:'2,3'}];

var SelectedProd = ['2,3'];

var a = arr.filter(x => {
    return _.intersection(
             x.products.split(','), SelectedProd[0].split(',')).length>0;
});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Explanation :

Lodash [_.intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#intersection) returns intersection of two arrays if it exists, or else returns []. We use a filter to filter only those objects where the intersection is non-empty

Comment: Im running with your Solution thx. One more Question if nothing is Selected is there something like var a = arr.filter(....).if(selected===null) return arr;
At the moment im checking it Simple with if before Filtering. Just want to know if I can attach something like that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get this object from the server, modify it, either by injecting a new Array property containing CSV's in Array format or replacing products entirely with an array. Your final array should be something like the following before binding:

`[

    {id = 1, products=[1,2]},
    {id = 2, products=[1]}  ... ]`

Please mark as answer if this helps

Comment: Is there a Solution without modifying it? Because I use it in more Functions than only this Filter. And still its not a Solution how then to Filter the Objects how I wanted to?

Comment: If all your Server Response objects are similar, you can easily create a simple Mapper module which would take care of the Response Objecct transformations.  With regards to your question on filtering : What you can do is use the indexOf JS operation within a foreach loop iterating through your Array of objects. If the indexOf operation returns a non -1 value for each of the selected products you can add it to your final result set. This should do the trick.

Comment: No they are mostly all Different. This is coming like this because it is needed like it is. But If you explain how to Modify then I could do it only in the Filter. And in there do the Filtering

Comment: @AkAk47 : Please refer to my above comment for the filtering logic, Mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: @AkAk47 : A word of advice, it is highly practical to use a mapper layer. You should advisably never try to bind server side responses directly to UI before transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the items using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to search for the selected items in the string:

```js
const findIemsByProducts = (items, selectedProd) => {
  const selected = selectedProd[0].split(','); // convert the selected products to array
  
  return items.filter((item) => // filter the items
    selected.some((productId) => // if at least one of the selected
      item.products.includes(productId) // is in the products string
    ));
}

var items = [  
  {id: 1, products: '1,2'},
  {id: 2, products: '1'},
  {id: 3, products: '3'},  
  {id: 4, products: '1,2,3'},
  {id: 5, products: '2,3'}
];

var SelectedProd = ['2,3'];

var results = findIemsByProducts(items, SelectedProd);

console.log(results);
```

And the angular filter would be:

```
.filter('filterByProd', () => (items, selectedProd) => {
  const selected = selectedProd[0].split(','); // convert the selected products to array

  return items.filter((item) => // filter the items
    selected.some((productId) => // if at least one of the selected
      item.products.includes(productId) // is in the products string
    ));
});
```